# Display JQuery Datepicker Today button only to a specific control

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

We are having multiple datepickers in our application. But we wanted to display Today button only in one page.

How can we show Today button only to a specific control?

I tried the below options:
1) Added class in the beforeshow of the datepicker

```
 beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
            $('#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-current').addClass('repositoryDate');
        }
```

2) I also tried to add class directly to the datepicker

```
 $("#val_effective_date").datepicker({
        showOn: 'both',
        dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yy',
        buttonImage: glSiteName + '/Content/Images/Icons/Calendar.png',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        buttonText: 'Currrent Date',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        altFormat: 'yymm',
        minDate: new Date($("#createdDate").val()),
        maxDate: new Date(9999, 12, 31),
        //onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
        //    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date());
        //},
        onChangeMonthYear: function (y, m, i) {
            var d = i.selectedDay;
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(y, m - 1, OnMonthYearChangeDateCheck(d, m - 1, y)));
        },
        beforeShow: function (input,inst) {
            $('#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-current').addClass('dataValidationDate');
        }
    }).next('.ui-datepicker-current').addClass('repositoryDate')
```

Then in the css added the below style

```
.repositoryDate{
visibility:visible
}
```

Comment: What are you tried so far?

Comment: Add your code in question so People can give answer to your specific problem.

Comment: Updated my query to include datepicker code

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve --> if you want the 'Today' button to only one datepicker, then do not call the showButtonPanel in the creation of all datepickers, just the one you want.
If you want to hide the button with a class you need to do it with setTimeout, because the datepicker builds itself after you add the class.

Comment: I need Close button to be displayed in all the datepickers. But Today button should be displayed only in one datepicker. showButtonPanel displays both Today and Close buttons.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want exactly: check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PQfDc/465/).

**HTML**

```
<p>Without today button</p>
<input class="datepicker hide_today" type="text">

<p>Without done button</p>
<input class="datepicker hide_done" type="text">

<p>With both buttons</p>   
<input class="datepicker" type="text">
```

**JS**

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    showButtonPanel: true,
    beforeShow: function(ele, obj) {
        obj.dpDiv.removeClass("hide_today hide_done");
        if($(ele).hasClass("hide_today")) obj.dpDiv.addClass("hide_today");
        if($(ele).hasClass("hide_done")) obj.dpDiv.addClass("hide_done"); 
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
.hide_today .ui-datepicker-buttonpane button:first-child
{
    display: none;
}
.hide_done .ui-datepicker-buttonpane button:last-child
{
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do something like this:
(Based on your code)
On the beforeShow:(of all the datepickers you want without the Today)

```
 beforeShow: function (input,inst) {
   todayBtnHandler();
 }



function todayBtnHandler(){
    setTimeout(function() {
               $(".ui-datepicker-current").hide();}, 50);    
              }
}
```

[Working fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/d95oku1m/8/)

Comment: Thanks Ziv. Your solution works fine when we initially load the datepicker. But when user tries to change the year, month or click on next,previous, today button is reappearing. To fix this issue, we need to call todayBtnHandler in onChangeMonthYear event.

Comment: yeah you can add that... is that a problem?

Comment: No. After adding additional call in the onChangeMonthYear event, everything is working as expected.